# Excel Macros not working in CatiaV5

Tags: excel, office365, vba

I have enabled macros and I also have the pro version of Microsoft Office 365. I want to input the coordinates of an Airfoil in CatiaV5.

Can anyone help me out with this? Is the problem related to Visual Basic? I also downloaded the Visual Basic 8 but nothing seems to help.

> You do not have appropriate license to use this functionality in the
>   design environment

the link to the picture!   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gma9f.jpg

Comment: can't upload picture as no reputation.

Comment: You can post a link to the picture and someone with higher reputation can edit it into the post for you.

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gma9f.jpg

Comment: Looks to me like it can't find your licence for using VBA with your office package, if this should be included in your package, you probably need to contact the vendor who sold you the product.

Comment: I got the product online using my student id in germany. This is a PRO version of Office 365. I am relinstalling office right now. But seems like there are very few experts on VBA and Excel related License problems.

Comment: This is not Excel related question, it is CatiaV5 and it in not even programming question. Did you check this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nP_gErfA5IQ

Comment: i did. i get the same error. So it must be programming related.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't an error related to your Microsoft Office License.

The error message is an COM / ActiveX-related error which indicates that the ActiveX-Component that are you trying to use and that ships with CatiaV5 isn't licensed correctly.

Check if your CatiaV5-License includes support for automation. That's the problem here.

The following document indicates that CatiaV5 must be opened before you execute any macro:
http://www.mediafire.com/view/tl16tj3kdsa3gc3/Excel+to+CATIA.pdf

Comment: I have it opened. It can't be a Catia related problem as others from the Uni have the same license and can use macros. :/

Comment: Are you using a 32 Bit or 64 Bit-Version of Office? Do you know in which DLL the COM-Object is included? You can try to re-register it via regsvr32 manually.

Comment: i am using 32 bit version of office and my computer is 64 bit. That should not be the problem can it? looks like my Catia is the problem

Comment: Your combination is okay if Catia is 32bit too. I'm running out of ideas, sorry :(

Comment: I assume my Catia is 64 bit can this be the root of the problem?But my catia is not in the x86 folder of programfiles but just in programfiles folder so?

Comment: In general all tools which are communicating via an automation interface should have the same platform (both 32 or both 64-Bit) if they use an in-process automation server. If the automation works via an out-of-process COM-Server this should work nonetheless. The manual says that Catia should be opened during the process. That's an indicator for an out-of-process COM-Server so I don't think it's a problem. However, is there a 32-Bit Catia available for you and can you ask the others if they run Catia as 32 or 64 Bit?

Comment: http://www.scripting4v5.com/additional-articles/catia-macro-terms-and-definitions/

Comment: could someone help me out?